# "Iron" version of common programming languages

Tags: asp.net, python, ruby-on-rails

I have recently seen new "Iron" languages get released into the .Net realm.
So far I've seen Iron Ruby and Iron Python. Are these just Mirosoft versions of already established languages/frameworks? If so are they syntactically equivalent?

I also remember back in the day that there was J++ and J# (Seems like an alternative Java implementation). I never really hear about wide adaptation of these languages. Do they fall into a the same category as the "iron" languages?

Comment: It's my understanding that Iron Python is not produced by Microsoft, but just makes use of the .NET Framework. As far as J++/J# goes, C# is basically Microsoft's response to Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are implementations of existing languages targetting the .Net/Mono framework. The original two, [IronPython](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Python) and [IronRuby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronRuby), were at some point developed as research by Microsoft. IronPython is no longer supported by Microsoft and they have let IronRuby go as well.  Information on them releasing the languages from their control can be found in this [article](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2010/10/22/microsoft_kills_dynamic_languages_projects/).

Other developers have followed suit and named their languages with "Iron" as a prefix. The Iron languages aren't the only language implementations developed target .Net though.  Languages such as [Boo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boo_%28programming_language%29) (a python dialect) target .Net for example.